# can't upload high resolution image to production and nothing shows in the logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Have a Rails app.
All basic stuff: Carrierwave etc.

Also have a production server. Regular Ubuntu, with Unicorn.

Trying to upload a high resolution image (like 10Mb JPG) to Production - and it does not work. Error `Something went wrong` (http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a62vxi592). But no errors show up in any of the logs. Like literally it says everywhere that everything is fine.

But can't reproduce this problem on localhost. In other words - it works on localhost just finen with any image size.

Does anyone know what I could do to fix it?

---

Edit:
Here's `nginx.conf`

```
    client_body_in_file_only clean;
    client_body_buffer_size 32K;

    client_max_body_size 300M;

    sendfile on;
    send_timeout 300s;

    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
```

`sites_available`:
server {

```
  listen 80;
  server_name devruck.us *.devruck.us;
  root /home/ruckus/apps/devruck.us/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    if ($request_filename ~* ^.*?\.(eot)|(ttf)|(woff)$){
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }

    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn_staging_ruckus;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a `client_max_body_size` issue..as it defaults to `1m` in your nginx.conf: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size

Comment: client_max_body_size 300M;

Comment: Can you check your `sites-available` and see if nothing else is overwriting it ?

Comment: client_max_body_size 4G;

Comment: may be a timeout issue? what happens if you increase the timeout?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the timeout value?